# Extract information from array

Tags: java, string, arraylist, hashmap

I am having a array like `String[] selectedJobs = {"job,1","job,2", "Job2,1", "job3,1"};`

I want to extract information like

```
Job -> 1,2

Job2 -> 1

Job3 -> 1

Map<String, List<String>> jobs = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
```

and I want to **store each job with corresponding list of integers in map**.

How to do this ?

Answer (score 2):

1. split the 1st string on "," -> "job", "1"
2. check there is a "job" key in the map, if not create it and put a new arraylist for that key
3. add "1" to the arraylist
4. loop

Comment: Thanks. I blocked  but your idea "check there is a "job" key in the map, if not create it and put a new arraylist for that key" cleared my error. It is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

What have you tried? The algorithm shouldn't be tricky: Go through your array, split on "," for each String, and put it in the HashMap you describe.